# Having the problem in fetching the sqlite data base

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am facing the problem in the fetching the data from the **sqlite** database.

I try like this but my data is not getting fetched:

```
+(void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath
{
JourneyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (JourneyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = "select JourneyID,JourneyName,LocationName,Description from UserJourney";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            //NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectStmt, 0);
            NewJourney *journeyobj = [[NewJourney alloc]init]; 
/**/when my pointer come at this line it goes out of the scope My  journeyobj.journeyname ,journeyobj.journeylocation and journeyobj.journeydescription is not getting the value.**
            journeyobj.journeyname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 3)];
            journeyobj.journeylocation = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 4)];
            journeyobj.journeydescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 5)];
            journeyobj.isDirty = NO;

            [appDelegate.journeyList addObject:journeyobj];
            [journeyobj release];

        }
    }
}
else 
{
    sqlite3_close(database);
}

}
```

What is the problem??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, make sure you only ever have one connection to sqlite open at any time in any thread. Multiple connections won't work.

Comment: Yes I have only one connections

Answer (score 0):

Please check that, your database has values for these all fields.

I think, there will be nil value for JourneyName,LocationName,Description.

So, before binding these value, first check like below:

NSString *strJourneyName = @"";

char *JourneyNameChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);

```
if (JourneyNameChars == NULL){

strJourneyName = @"";
}

else{

strJourneyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: JourneyNameChars];
}
```

Check this for all fields which has datatype = TEXT.

Hope it will be helpful to you and solve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: You says that, your program has value out of scope at below line: "journeyobj.journeyname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 3)];
".  I am saying that, check it's value in database. I think it will be nil/blank. So, it will give error in your function. So, just check for TEXT value like my answer as above. Let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Then How can we avoid that null value And make app run And fetch results also

Comment: As my answer says, if value will be null then it will store "" to the variable. And your app will not crash.

Comment: I try the your code it work but the app getting crash at second  time loop

Comment: Great. So, you have resolve the database problem. Regarding crash in loop, then you have to check for details in you code.

Comment: It's fine but how can add the sqlite data like                    double longitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 0);
double latitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 1);
  NSLog(@"%f and %f",longitude,latitude); into NSString I have more then 100 data(longitude,latitude)) in the database

Comment: I try like this but not work It show me the warning my code is like that            NSString *coords =[[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:"%f,%f",longitude,latitude]autorelease]; And warning is passing argument 1 of 'initWithFormat:' from incompatible

Comment: Data can be retrived in the same mmaner using NSString like NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 0)];
. And then you can NSLog like (@"%@ and %@", longitude,latitude);